# Angular routing doesn't work with latest jquery versions

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to write project on LoopbackJS, Angular and Angular-Materialize.
My app.js looks like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
'ngRoute',
'ngResource',
'ui.router',
'lbServices',
'ui.materialize'
])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$routeProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'views/authenticate.html',
      service: 'AuthService',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl'
    })
    .state('declarations', {
      url: '/declarations',
      templateUrl: 'views/declarations.html',
      controller: 'DeclarationsCtrl'
    })
    .state('payments', {
      url: '/payments',
      templateUrl: 'views/payments.html',
      controller: 'PaymentsCtrl'
    })
    .state('reports', {
      url: '/reports',
      templateUrl: 'views/reports.html',
      controller: 'ReportsCtrl'
    })
    .state('services', {
      url: '/services',
      templateUrl: 'views/services.html',
      controller: 'ServicesCtrl'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}])

.run(['$rootScope', '$state', function ($rootScope, $state) {
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
  // redirect to login page if not logged in
  if (next.authenticate && !$rootScope.currentAccount) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevent current page from loading
    $state.go('forbidden');
  }
});
}]);
```

In my index.html:

```
  <script src="bower_components/jquery-2.1.4/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-materialize/src/angular-materialize.js"></script>
```

When I load JQuery 1.6.4 all my routes work fine, and I am redirected to authenticate.html page. But when I try using later versions, I get index.html page, without any errors in console. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I have to use later versions of JQuery, because angular-materialize doesn't work with 1.6.4.
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: @Juhana Angular 1.4.1

Comment: You should post a plunkr if possible

Comment: @Jan, I never used plunkr. I don't know, what I've done there, bot here's the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z3XCy7GOhrAmifSA6noK